# Subversion workflow: force update, build, test before commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, workflow, pre-commit-hook

Is it possible to create an svn commit hook that would confirm the working directory has been svn-updated, built and tested before commit?  I want to at least ensure that code has been compiled and tested with the latest code in trunk before the developer can commit.  This would prevent integration issues in trunk when developers have been modifying different source code that results in a failed build.

An alternative would be to prevent commit if there exist any files that have been updated (but not necessaryily modified in the working directory).

As an aside, as mentioned in a previous question, my work commits binaries as well as source. One given reason for this is if there is a binary file conflict on commit you know that there has been a change to the source for that binary, so you need to run svn-update and recompile.  It also makes merging and updates a pain. I realise that if developers were to update before commit, it would be less likely to need this check.

Answer (score 1):

SVN itself ensures that the file(s) has been updated. You don't have to ensure that people are checking in an update file.

For the compile / test part you can have client side hooks using TortoiseSVN which will compile the code and run the tests as part of a pre-commit hook. Caveat being that you cannot really be sure that every developer has the hooks setup.

You can also look at something similar to [Rake Commit tasks](https://github.com/pgr0ss/rake_commit_tasks)

Below are the steps that the above does:

> 1. Prompts for a commit message
> 2. Adds new files to subversion
> 3. Deletes missing files from subversion
> 4. svn update
> 5. Runs the default rake task (which should run the tests)
> 6. Checks cruisecontrol.rb to see if the build is passing
> 7. Checks in the code

Comment: Yes but svn will only ensure modified files have been updated before commit. Say there is
a binary that is built from two source files.  Two developers both check
out the same revision but modify only one source file each.  If they don't update and test
before commit, it's possible they could check in code that, together, would
fail. (eg a functon in source1 is removed that the new revision of source2 relies on)  It's an edge case that apparently they have been bitten by in the
past.

Comment: Looking at the svn rake commit task (and the steps you just pasted in, thanks! :) ), it looks very close to what I would want in tortoisesvn.